# How can I control GCE LB to create max N TCP connections with my backend instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

For each request that a client makes through a load balancer, the load balancer maintains two TCP connections. One connection is with the client and the other connection is to a back-end instance.
GCE LoadBalancer is creating lots of TCP connections with my backend instance, how can i control this ?

GCP docs says

"Traffic from the load balancer to your instances has an IP address in the range of 130.211.0.0/22. When viewing logs on your load balanced instances, you will not see the source address of the original client. Instead, you will see source addresses from this range."

That means ideally LB can open max 2 pow 10 * 2 pow 16 = 67108864 TCP connections with backend instance.
Here
    2 pow 10 for IP range
    2 pow 16 for port range per IP.

How can I control GCE LB to create max N TCP connections with my backend instance?

Comment: Load balancers will typically reuse connections to backends when appropriate, and each connection will have an idle timeout. Are you seeing a large number of TCP connection from the LB to your backend?

Comment: Yes I am seeing thousands of connections from the LB to my backend.

Answer (score 2):

Currently HTTP Load Balancer does not expose connection limit controls. Backend Service connection limit is capped at 64K per backend. In reality you can expect to see up to around 2-3k active connections per backend, depending on the load pattern.

While I wouldn't be concerned about 2-3k connections that much, if you absolutely need to avoid having that many simultaneous connections, consider implementing dynamic health check and return *unhealthy* status when number of connections goes over defined threshold. Unhealthy status would prevent backend instance to get new connections, but you'll need to figure out how to deal with the overflow load, maybe by Autoscaling your Backend Service.